# Импорт модулей Yandex Angular (ymaps.modules import angular)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, angular5

Как правильно сделать импорт модуля ymaps (например: yandex/mapsapi-heatmap в Angular) import{ Heatmap} from 'ymaps-heatmap', как быть? На момент импорта модуля yandex карта еще не загружена и возникает ошибка (Нужно создавать экземпляр класса по требованию) var heatmap = new Heatmap();
Смотрел другие npm пакеты например google-markercluster (https://github.com/novakand/googlemaplib.markercluster/blob/master/index.js) строка 334 (при создании экземпляра класса происходит инициализация) function MarkerClusterer(map, opt_markers, opt_options) {
  this.extend(MarkerClusterer, google.maps.OverlayView);
Может кто-то сталкивался, буду благодарен любой помощи!

Comment: грузите ее через динамический импорт

Comment: У меня идет переключение карт ( с одной карты на другую, при динамическом импорте модуль подгружается только один раз, в последующих случаях, модуля в ymaps нет) Этого class вообще не существует

Comment: не понял, какой class? какая разница сколько раз грузится модуль? смысл в том что вы проводите махинации с вашей библиотекой только после того как яндекс карты загружены

Comment: Вот именно, при  повторной инициализации и повторном динамическом импорте в ymaps нет модуля

Comment: я не понимаю что значит "в ymaps нет модуля" :(

Comment: при первой инициализации yandex в объекте ymaps class DrawingManager присутствует см. рис (https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNi3LCJSDtR6oEsB7VdrxvExnYhmAWkhxKtQcy1-I7reKIp_QmOFoh0AVbxdMf1fA?key=aGp4M1F0THg2c3RjYk9vLWFtaDNGQVdKWEUyQ1hB) во втором случае (при повторной инициализация при динамической загрузке этого объекта (class) уже нет см.рис ( https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNoFn3MZOOtjQi33GMM4xuuyqL9mzauOjBfXchTTj3YAFATu5VhxOTEu-nwLew-Hg?key=MFEyN1M1TXFlQjRza2g0WjRhMVVicUxIbW9ONGlR, Такая ситуация наблюдается и при динамической инициализации у Leaflet